# SQL Server 2008 Orphaned Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-administration, orphan

I am using SQL Server 2008 through SQL Server Management Studio

I have never seen this before:

Often, when refactoring a database as I have been doing most of my day, I use the following to find references to columns, tables and other procedures in my existing procedures:

```
select *
from sys.sql_modules
where [definition] like '%SomethingImLookingFor%'
```

This is nothing special, I'm sure lots of database heads have done it before.

However, I noticed the results contained a procedure that looks to have been a total accident when created(If ever actually created). In the database I have a procedure named `ChatObject_Remove`, this appeared in my query because I was looking for anything referencing the term `%Remove%`. But I also see a *ghost* procedure called `zzChatObject_Remove`

In SSMS when I expand the database's `Programmability -> Stored Procedures` I see `ChatObject_Remove`, but not `zzChatObject_Remove`.

I have tried refreshing this group and the ghost still does not appear.

I tried to use the statement

```
drop procedure [dbo].[zzChatObject_Remove]
```

which returned an error saying it either didn't exist or I didn't have permission.

I tried to create a procedure called `zzChatObject_Remove` and it allowed me to do it (but now I had 2 objects in `sql_modules` with a definition for `create procedure zzChatObject_Remove ...`). I then deleted the new one which it allowed, and the ghost, as expected, is still in the modules table and I cannot touch it.

Has anyone seen this before? Where else could this be? Could it do any harm? How can I get rid of this seemingly orphaned procedure in the `sys.sql_modules` table?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Just my luck, seeing a ghost around Halloween time...

Comment: Have you checked to see if it's in another Schema?

Comment: Execute this statement in Database context and see if it gives you some information that will give you some idea where it came from when it was created

Select * from sys.procedures where [type] = 'P'

Comment: Does the stored procedure have a trailing space or Unicode character in the name?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see where it comes up:

```
exec sp_MSforeachdb '
    select ''?'' [db]
    , s.name [schema]
    , o.name [object]
    , o.type_desc 
    from [?].sys.objects o 
    inner join sys.schemas s 
        on s.schema_id = o.schema_id 
    where o.name = ''zzChatObject_Remove''
'
```

Or the following:

```
select *
from sys.sql_modules sm
inner join sys.objects o 
    on o.object_id = sm.object_id
inner join sys.schemas s 
    on s.schema_id = o.schema_id 
where sm.description like '%zzChatObject_Remove%'
```

Also, to check, is this proc defined in sql_modules, or is it showing because it's referenced in the code of another procedure?